# filtering data based on delimiter in shell

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, command-line

I have a file with data as follows:

```
"google1|yoo|dummy|yes|wow|/" + VARIABLE + "/"
"google2|hub|lab|dummy|yes|/" + VARIABLE + "/"
"google3|short|lab|yoo|/" + VARIABLE + "/"
"google4|hello|good-guy|bad-girl|lol|dummy|/" + VARIABLE + "/"
"google5|good-guy|a4-123|yoo|/" + VARIABLE + "/"
"google6|bad-girl|b4-124|hub|/" + VARIABLE + "/"
```

Now, I want to get a list of strings between delimiter "|" (pipe).

Output should be as

```
yoo
dummy
yes
wow
hub
hello
good-guy
bad-girl
a4-123
b4-124
dummy
lol
short
lab
```

Basically, I want to have unique values from the list of strings after delimiter filter. 
I tried using awk as

```
awk -F"|" '{gsub(/\).*/,"",$2);print $2}' file
```

But, I get wrong data.

Comment: there is a typo between input file and expected output.. `good-boy` should be `good-guy`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have `grep` with `pcre` option:

```
$ grep -oP '\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' ip.txt | sort -u
a4-123
b4-124
bad-girl
dummy
good-guy
hello
hub
lab
lol
short
wow
yes
yoo
```

- `-o` print only matching pattern
- `-P` use pcre regex
- `\|\K` positive lookbehind to see if `|` is there before our string to be extracted

  - similarly, `(?=\|)` positive lookahead to see if there is `|` after our string to be extracted
- `[^|]+` string to be extracted - simply negate `|` and get one or more of such character
- `sort -u` to get unique value

If you want to preserve order in which these strings are found:

```
$ grep -oP '\|\K[^|]+(?=\|)' ip.txt | awk '!seen[$0]++'
yoo
dummy
yes
wow
hub
lab
short
hello
good-guy
bad-girl
lol
a4-123
b4-124
```

Comment: +1 was just about to suggest the same but with `(?<=\|).*?(?=\|)`

Comment: yes.. Better option and works perfectly :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about order, you could use a perl hash to ensure uniqueness e.g.

```
$ perl -lne '$h{$_}++ for /(?<=\|).*?(?=\|)/g; END{print for keys %h}' file
short
b4-124
lol
yes
bad-girl
lab
yoo
good-guy
hub
dummy
hello
a4-123
wow
```

See [creating a hash with regex matches in perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14624059/4440445)

Comment: how about `perl -lne 'for (/(?<=\|).*?(?=\|)/g) {print if !$h{$_}++}' file` to print in same order as found...

Comment: @Sundeep doh! of course... much better - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

what about the following ?

```
cut file -d'|' -f2,3,4 | tr '|' '\n'
```

The above command will print fixed number of columns (3). If you want to print variable number of columns, up to first occurrence of `/`, you could use something like:

```
cut -d'/' -f1 file | cut  -d'|' -f2- | tr '|' '\n'
```

Comment: This works.. But -f2,3,4 (here I dont know how many maximum will be there) but atleast not more than 20. Is there a way to give range ?

Comment: Thanks and works.. But extra spaces.. so i did at the end as `| grep '[^[:blank:]]'| sort -u` :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your output has "dummy" repeating. This is what I get with the script below --

```
   awk -f f1.awk /tmp/f1
    short
    hub
    wow
    hello
    a4-123
    b4-124
    yes
    yoo
    lol
    bad-girl
    good-guy
    lab
    dummy

    cat f1.awk 
    {
      n=split($1,a,"|")

      for(i=2; i<n; i++) {
        arr[a[i]] = a[i] 
      } 
    }   
    END{
      for (var in arr) 
        print(var)  
    }
```